# Find visual studio release on which an exe/dll was build (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows, visual-studio, build

If I build an exe/dll with an "Enterprise" Visual Studio will it be different from the one which I build with a "Community" VS?

Are there any ways to determine if an exe/dll was built with "Enterprise" version or "Community" version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Versions of VS such as Enterprise and Community are just the differences in features available in the Visual Studio IDE.

When you build your solution/project, that's got to do with the .NET Version you're using, and different build types such as a Debug build and a Release build.

Think of the two as the body of a car and the engine; IDE is the body and the host of modifications you can do to it, and .NET is the engine.

So if you use the same .NET version and build (Release/Debug) there is no difference in the executables whether you build them on Community or Enterprise.

Comment: Thank you! I understand this car/engine analogy but my doubts come from somewhere else.

Did Microsoft make some optional headers when build with VS to determine the VS version (For legal purposes. If a published exe was build with community then it's OK but when it was build with enterprise you have to pay for a licence).

I ask this out of curiosity.

Comment: What's the doubt you have?

Comment: Sorry I pressed enter too early. I have edited my comment.

Comment: That I'm not sure if I can answer. Here's more info on licensing though:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/262916/understanding-visual-studio-community-edition-license